# WooCommerce - Redirecting a User after They've Reset Their Password

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I'm setting up a WooCommerce shop for a client and he has requested that the user be redirected back to the login form after the reset password form has been submitted.

Is this possible? Which function controls this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm just facing the same question. I think the function that controls this is in the file `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php`. I changed the following line:

```
wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'reset', 'true', remove_query_arg( array( 'key', 'login' ) ) ) );
```

with

```
wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
```

With that change, you get redirected to the my-account page, where the customer can log in, but of course there are two problems doing that:

1. The customer gets no message the the password recovery was successful
2. Doing a WooCommerce update, the file gets overwritten with the original file

Would be great, if someone could come up with a "update-secure" solution.

Best regards
Christoph

Comment: Hi Christoph, that actually helps me a bit, so I appreciate that. Regards, Daniel.

Comment: Changing plugin files directly is not best practice. Doing so prevents you from cleanly updating plugins, as you have to manually apply the same patch with each upgrade. In general, if a plugin provides hooks to accomplish what you're trying to do (as WooCommerce appears to), it's much better to use those first.

Answer (score 13):

A much cleaner solution is to redirect using the `woocommerce_customer_reset_password` action:

```
function woocommerce_new_pass_redirect( $user ) {
  wp_redirect( get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')));
  exit;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_reset_password', 'woocommerce_new_pass_redirect' );
```

This code can be placed in `functions.php`.

Comment: I think this one should be the accepted answer. it uses woocommerce and wp native funcions. Is upgrade safe and easy to test.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, this one is a better answer using hooks and actions.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked me about doing this and I think I'm going to talk them out of it, but here's what I came up with so that you could see the message and then be redirected in 5 seconds. Add a message/link to let them know you'll be redirecting. Plus, this will last through a WooCommerce upgrade if you add the template file to your theme

Add the form-lost-password.php template file to your theme and add the following code:

```
        if ( $_GET[reset] = true && ( 'lost_password' == $args['form']) ) {
            $my_account_url = get_site_url() . '/my-account';
            echo "<script>window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace('$my_account_url')}, 5000)</script>";
        }
```

If you dont want the time delay get rid of the window.setTimeout() and just use window.location.replace('$my_account_url').